# How to automatically split work among multiple pods of a postgres k8s cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, divide-and-conquer

In learning k8s, I followed a [tutorial](https://adamtheautomator.com/postgres-to-kubernetes/#Deploying_PostgreSQL_to_Kubernetes_Manually) for "Deploying PostgreSQL to Kubernetes Manually" using ConfigMap and PersistentVolume. In the end, I was able to get the pods running in microk8s:

```
$ microk8s.kubectl get pods -o wide 
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE   IP            NODE   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
postgres-555c5c6d4d-hp55z   1/1     Running   2 (5m28s ago)   67m   10.1.98.155   abox   <none>           <none>
postgres-555c5c6d4d-zclns   1/1     Running   1 (5m28s ago)   67m   10.1.98.153   abox   <none>           <none>
postgres-555c5c6d4d-8h4ph   1/1     Running   1 (5m28s ago)   67m   10.1.98.154   abox   <none>           <none>
```

And I was able to access each pod from the host Ubuntu OS using `psql`:

```
$ psql -h 10.1.98.155  -U appuser --password -p 5432 -d postgresPassword: 
psql (14.7 (Ubuntu 14.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), server 12.10 (Debian 12.10-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I understand that there are three instances/pods of postgres now running on my machine. If so, I wanted to distribute a job (e.g. finding the `SUM()` of a column in a table) equally to  the three instances. More specifically, I wanted to have:

1. each postgres instance have a copy of the same database table,
2. each instance assigned a third of the unique ids and find the `SUM()` of another column for those ids
3. add the sum values to get an overall sum value, and write it back to a new table in each postgres instance.

the above steps can be done by sending SQL statements via the database client psql to each instance IP.

I can think of a naive way to write a bash script to do this given the specific IP addresses from the terminal output. But I was just wondering if there is an automatic way of doing this kind of job-splitting in k8s. More specifically,

**My Questions are:**

1. are the IP addresses such as `10.1.98.155` stable (e.g. between reboots of the host machine)? If not, what is the correct way of automatically getting the IP addresses of each `postgres` instance?
2. will the number of postgres instances change if I have less or more resources (automatic scaling)?
3. are there more canonical ways of doing this kind of job splitting inside k8s (rather than writing a outside script)?

Answer (score 0):

***Are the IP addresses such as 10.1.98.155 stable (e.g. between reboots of the host machine)? If not, what is the correct way of automatically getting the IP addresses of each postgres instance?***

No, the IP addresses of the pods or containers won’t be stable and will keep on changing for pod restarts and for pod recreation. If you are creating these pods using a CICD pipeline in that pipeline you can use below steps.

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces > pods.csv #for listing the pods and storing the data to csv file`

Use a small script for passing the details to the command below

`kubectl describe pod <pod id from csv>`

Here you can grep the IP address of these pods from the output of the above command and store the values to the same csv file.

***will the number of postgres instances change if I have less or more resources (automatic scaling)?***

Yes, auto scaling is affected by resource availability. If you have less resources you can’t scale your database upwards or horizontally. However, even though you have enough or surplus resources if your database is not getting hitted with the traffic, auto scaling function won’t be triggered and the resources will be left under utilized so, while doing the capacity planning you need to consider your user base and scale the application accordingly.

***Are there more canonical ways of doing this kind of job splitting inside k8s (rather than writing an outside script)?***

> Since you want to have a split in the operations performed you can
> configure a postgres cluster and perform read and write operations
> separately, there is an operator called kubegres available using which
> you can manage your postgresql deployment easily on kubernetes. This
> operator supports multiple functions such as:
>
> - It creates a cluster of PostgreSql servers with data replication enabled:    it creates a Primary PostgreSql pod and a number of
>   Replica PostgreSql pods    and replicates primary's database in
>   real-time to Replica pods.
> - It manages fail-over: if a Primary PostgreSql crashes, it automatically    promotes a Replica PostgreSql as a Primary.
> - It has a data backup option allowing to dump PostgreSql data regularly in a    given volume.
> - It provides a very simple YAML with properties specialized for PostgreSql.
> - It is resilient, has over 55 automated test cases and has been running in    production.
> - It works with the [PostgreSql containers](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) created by the [Docker
>   Official Images
>   team:](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/) it does
>   not ship nor require a custom Docker image to work.

***Note:*** The information on kubegres is taken from official postgresql documentation go through this [link](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/kubegres-is-available-as-open-source-2197/) for more information